# How to obfuscate fat Scala Jar with Proguard and SBT

Tags: scala, sbt, proguard, obfuscation

I've managed to obfuscate my Scala code but I can't figure out how to run obfuscation against a jar file that is built by `sbt assembly` step. Or at least how to build a fat jar during the `proguard` step. I found that there is a `injar` argument for proguard but I have no clue how to apply it to `build.sbt`. Can someone please point me to how I can do this.

**UPD** Actually the JAR that is built by Proguard contains only obfuscated classes and not a single class from those that are ignored by Proguard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To run a Proguard obfuscation against a jar file that was built by `assembly` task previously you should override `inputs` setting in build.sbt:

```
proguardInputs in Proguard := Seq((assemblyOutputPath in assembly).value)
```

This would specify your fat jar as a single input for Proguard. Also you probably want to modify the input libraries that are used for obfuscation. Here is an example of how to exclude all the libraries:

```
proguardLibraries in Proguard := Seq()
```

Finally disable input filter since you have only one source of classes:

```
proguardInputFilter in Proguard := { file => None }
```

The setting above is required because Proguard will exclude `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file by default. Also merge step is no longer required since `assembly` task already performed this step:

```
proguardMerge in Proguard := false
```

And finally add `assembly` dependency to your Proguard task:

```
(ProguardKeys.proguard in Proguard) <<= (ProguardKeys.proguard in Proguard).dependsOn(assembly)
```

Comment: Hi @Zyoma, I'm unable to use the sbt-proguard plugin. Sbt keeps complaining that it's unable to resolve the dependency. Did you have to add a resolver to your build.sbt file to get proguard working? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Zyoma, what's the sbt command you ran to produce the obfuscated jar?

Comment: I had to change the last line to 
(proguard in Proguard) :=  ((proguard in Proguard).dependsOn(assembly)).value

Also, it seems the plugin a sbt version of 1.3.*, but I might be mistaken there.